# bootstrap prepend sign not aligning correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working hard on my first project, but I've hit a stumbling block which I've been working to try to fix for the past three hours, but to no avail, I've searched the bootstrap manual and googled everything I can possibly think of, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

I'm trying to prepend an address sign to the form input below, but for some reason it doesn't want to stay aligned, if anyone is able to point me in the right direction on how to solve this I'd much appreciate it, thank you very much.

[image: screenshot]

```
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="inputUsername">Username</label>
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                <small class="form-text text-muted">
                    Small text here.
                </small>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <!-- placeholder -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to add `input-group` class , Here is working demo :

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 
 <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="inputUsername">Username</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />              
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">
                    Small text here.
                </small>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <!-- placeholder -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much for your help, it's much appreciated, I did have a feeling I was missing a div but didn't realize that's where it was missing from.

Answer (score 0):

the code below works for Bootstrap 4:

[image]

```
 <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-auto">
  <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Username</label>
  <div class="input-group mb-2">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <div class="input-group-text">@</div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
</div>
```